Stacking on a Wild Reverse Draw 4 Card in UNO Show 'Em No Mercy
We are a few people who are playing Uno Show 'Em No Mercy and we can't agree on if you are allowed to put a Wild Draw 6 Card or Wild Draw 10 Card on a Wild Reverse Draw 4 Card?

You can stack another draw card as long as the draw value is equal to or higher then the last one. In your example both of them work as they have a greater value then the Wild Reverse Draw 4 Card.
UNO Show 'Em No Mercy Rules

Stacking - If someone plays a Draw Card (+2, +4, +6, +10) you can
“Stack” the penalty by playing a Draw Card from your hand of equal or
higher value. If you do, the card you played adds to the total penalty
for the next player. For example, if someone plays a +4 card on you,
and you can play a +6 on top of it, the next player is now forced to
draw 10 cards (unless they can play a Draw +6 or higher, then it goes
on to the next player). This continues until someone can’t play a Draw
Card that equals or exceeds the value of the last card played.
That player then takes the full penalty of all stacked Draw Cards. Ouch!

